# How do you change the launcher icon to visualize the active workspace?

Tags: unity, launcher, workspaces

I want the Unity launcher icon to show me (at a glance) on which workspace I am (as in most of the other desktop environments) - is there a way to?

I tried to search the issue but there are too many duplicate wordings like "how order/remove/resize launcher icons", and so on.

The closest one was this, but not sufficient either: http://www.techdrivein.com/2011/05/top-6-quicklists-for-ubuntu-1104-natty.html

Answer (score 4):

Not exactly what you've requested, which as answered is not possible but a decent alternative is the indicator-workspace. It displays the current WS number in the panel & allows switching WS's from it.

Available from this ppa

https://launchpad.net/~geod/+archive/ppa-geod

LP page

https://launchpad.net/indicator-workspaces

[image: showing on WS 2]

Comment: This indicator is absolutely amazing! I'm so lost without it :P

Answer (score 1):

As commented on the question, and converted to an answer ;)

> Your Unity Launcher cannot be moded unless you are prepared to do some
>   serious code-work. The Workspace Switcher does what you are asking for
>   (although not in just a glance) and also allows you to switch
>   workspaces if need be